# Print calculated values with headers after comparison

Tags: r, max, min

How can I print the header of values after I compare them?
I have some calculated values stored as per below:

```
Value1 12
Value2 6
Value3 7
Value4 5
```

How can I print the max among four values with the header?

I can only get the max among the values but not the header/description
For e.g.:

```
"print(max(Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4))"
```

gives me:

```
"12"
```

but I need the output as:

```
"Max. value is Value1 = 12"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you pass your object to `dput()` and paste the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are stored as single numeric objects as below, and named with some pattern `"ValueX"`, we can put them all into a list, then get index for max/min and `paste`:

```
# example data
Value1 <- 12
Value2 <- 6
Value3 <- 7
Value4 <- 5

# put all in a named vector
x <- mget(ls()[ grepl("^Value", ls()) ])

# then paste
ix <- which.max(x)
paste("Max. value is", names(x[ ix ]), "=", x[ ix ])
# [1] "Max. value is Value1 = 12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be this :

```
c <- data.frame(a = c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"), b = c("4","9","5"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

print(paste("Max. value is", str_c(c[which(c$b == max(c$b)), 1], c[which(c$b == max(c$b)), 2], sep = " = "), sep = " "))
```

Comment: If the data was in a dataframe, then simply: `with(df1[ which.max(df1$b), ], paste("Max. value is", a, "=", b))`